# Magento 1.9.4 checkout/onepage after login redirect to checkout/cart

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

Am using Magento 1.9. When customer login in checkout/onepage page, it redirect to customer/account.

I want to remove this flow.

If customer login in checkout/onepage page redirect to same page I mean checkout/cart page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the setting in Admin Panel.

1. Log in to Admin Panel
2. Go to System > Configuration Under Customers,
3. select Customer Configuration Expand the Login Options
4. Set “Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in” to No.
5. Save configuration.

Hope it would be helpful.
Thanks